# jQueryUI Tabs - Caching Images

Tags: browser, caching

I have a form split apart throughout 4 tabs. One of the tabs contains photos if the user has uploaded some. Under each photo is a button to delete the photo. It performs an AJAX call to delete the photo and load in a new input[file] field that the user can use to upload another photo.

This works fine. The problem is after the user uploads the new photo, it appears as if the old photo is still there. If the user refreshes the browser, it doesn't go away. The user literally has to hold shift and then refresh (bypass cache).

The problem most likely stems from the fact that the new image gets named the same as the old one... and the browser is simply pulling from it's cache.

What do I need to do to prevent that from occurring? I've already set {cache : false} on the jQueryUI tabs. I believe it has to do with the image being cached by the browser. Is there a way to tell the browser to not cache a few images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a parameter to the image tag source filename, such as the current timestamp to break the browser's cache? Something like:

```
<img src="something.jpg?234343234"/>
```

Comment: I did that, it worked. I used it as a band-aid, and then spent some time rewriting the engine that saves the images. Thank you for the quick response.